# Suggested improvement for "activity"

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

If users want to know their rejected edits, they need to go **activity** >> **suggestions** and click on "suggested edit" from the list of their suggested edits.

There is no link/tab provided for rejected edits, and users don't get notification when a suggestion got rejected. If DA provided a tab beside the **suggestions** tab for rejected suggestions, it would help users to improve their editing behavior.